# Powershell on Linux: Out-Gridview equivalent

Tags: linux, gui, powershell, shell-extension

I've been playing with Powershell on Linux. Is there a Powershell Commandlet or Module that does the equivalent of what the Out-GridView commandlet does on the Windows platform?

It displays the input (given as a table, dataframe) in a sortable window, similar to a spreadsheet. SOmetimes it is nice to look at this rather at than text in a shell console.

Can be a community-supplied commandlet/module, or even an external tool. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity, and Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome.

(I think I've asked this a few years ago on SO, but my question was removed after a while)

Comment: Export-Csv and open with Libre-/OpenOffice/SpreadSheet of your choice.

Comment: That is slow and brittle, and loses the benefits of piping, e.g. the objects with type information.

Comment: As the unix way of piping isn't with objects, you'd need to convert them anyway probaply with `ConvertTo-Json` and need an app that display that in GridView, at least LibreOffice can't due to this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534203/does-libreoffice-calc-support-json-file-importing-sorting) I checked before posting inititially.

Comment: I prefer Rstudio to Libreoffice. Rstudio has a gridview (the `View()` function) that does what I want, works well with nested/composite grid items, and `readr::read_csv()` gets the data-import job done much better than LibreOffice Calc. But Rstudio does not work in a pipe AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit goes to Stackoverflow user @js2010 who pointed me to a solution described in

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/out-gridview-returns/ .

This installs a solution coming from Microsoft themselves, and tests it:

```
Install-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.GraphicalTools
get-childitem | out-gridview
```

Update 2021: For Powershell 7.2 (or perhaps earlier), the `Out-Gridview` Commandlet has been moved into a new Module, [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-7.2) .